# Splitting Django CharField as if it's a string

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm taking user input into a Textarea widget, then looping by line, and trying to split the three "words" (first name, last name, email) from each line into a list, which I'll then deal with later. When I use split() on the line, though, it always splits into characters, which I assume is part of the CharField def'n of the field, meaning that it's not a string and the split() method won't behave as I want it to. Edit: even the `for` construct is failing - it's analyzing each character, instead of each line.

What's the workaround for that?

```
class UserImportForm(forms.Form):
    importtext = forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 40, 'rows': 15}))


elif "UserImport" in request.POST:
    g = UserImportForm(request.POST, prefix='usrimp')
    rawtext = g['importtext'].value()
    if g.is_valid():
        newusers = []
        for lines in rawtext:
            row = lines.split(" ")

            if len(row) == 3 and validate_email(row[2]):
                newusers.append(row)
```

Comment: When I split a CharField string it works correctly. Something else might be going on here?

Comment: why are you storing 3 different things in the same field?

Comment: I'm actually importing 3n things: n sets of users, with first name, last name, email for each. It's a field that allows pasting a file of user data, then parses it and, finally, creates the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is likely not the best way to do it, here's what I ended up doing. Still welcoming better answers!

```
    elif "UserImport" in request.POST:
        g = UserImportForm(request.POST, prefix='usrimp')

        if g.is_valid():
            rawtext = g.cleaned_data['importtext'].encode('utf8')

            rawtext = "".join(rawtext)
            rawtext = rawtext.split("\n")
            newusers = []
            for lines in rawtext:
                row = lines.split()
                if len(row) == 3:
                    try:
                        validate_email(row[2])
                        newusers.append([row[0],row[1],row[2],"processmore"])
                    except:
                        newusers.append([row[0],row[1],row[2],"Invalid email address"])
```